# Istio multi-cluster not syncing

Tags: istio, servicemesh

I configured 2 clusters with ISTIO [multi-cluster multi-primary on different networks](https://istio.io/v1.14/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/).

Using a sample pod running an nginx image, I was able to reach the second cluster from the other one (LoadBalancers of the E/W gateways and also the k8s API).

When I try to [verify the mesh](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/verify/) was successfully installed, the load balancing of an service doesn't works (it does not balance the request between the versions 1 and 2 between the clusters).

In istiod pod, in cluster1, I found this log:

```
2023-05-03T14:31:26.590441Z info    initializing Kubernetes credential reader for cluster cluster2
2023-05-03T14:31:26.590470Z error   Adding cluster_id from secret=cluster2: istio-system/istio-remote-secret-cluster2 1 error occurred:
    * failed creating config configStore for cluster cluster2: Get "https://172.26.0.2:8443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/customresourcedefinitions": context deadline exceeded


2023-05-03T14:31:26.590476Z info    Number of remote clusters: 1
```

Any idea about what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to configure the minikube clusters to start with `--network host`, and the `Metal LB` I had to configure with an IP range of my host network also, so the `LoadBalancers` got an reachable IP address.